# How to convert jax rs core response pdf in Spring MulitActionController

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I am consuming rest webservice to download pdf document using jax-rs client.

jax-rs returning response as javax.ws.rs.core.Response object.

Response.getMetadata() returning MessageHeader values in Map

Response.getEntity() - returning Messagebody as Object.

My Spring MVC webapplication is using MultiActionController. It returns only ModelandView.

```
public ModelAndView getPDF(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {

        javax.ws.rs.core.Response rsResponse = getPDFFromRestWS();

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.pdf");   

// how to set rsResponse.getEntity Object in HTTPServletResponse

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}
```

My Question is

How i will transfer the Jax-rs Response to HTTPServletResponse.

Comment: You want to use `readEntity(TypeYouWant.class)` instead of `getEntity()`. You can simply use `InputStream.class` if you just want the `InputStream`. Then do whatever you want with the `InputStream`

Comment: Sorry I am using Jdk 1.6. ReadEntity is in Jdk 1.7

Comment: What does the JDK have anything to do with it?

Comment: @peeskillet -  Yes, you are right. i misunderstood. The thing is i am using jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar. This jar not having readEntity method. Anyhow as you said I casted to InputStream (InputStream.class.cast(response.getEntity())) and It works. Thanks a lot peeskillet